# php pdo to display output of mysql query using variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to pdo and battling a little.

I want to populate a table with the results of a mysql query. the query will return a single result based on the the variable

have the following function:

```
 function get_editusers($db){     
    try { 
         $result = $db->query("SELECT firstname, middlename,surname,fullname,gender, birthdate,homelanguage,department,employeetype,employeestatus,idnumber FROM Persons where employeeid= :empid");  
         return $result;  
    } catch(PDOException $ex) { 
         return $ex; 
    } 
} 

$useredit= get_editusers($db);
```

I then use the following to output the values:

```
while($row = $useredit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
echo $row['firstname'];
echo $row['middelname'];
echo $row['surname'];
}
```

This however produces a blank result with no errors.

How can I correct this sytnax? Also I need to change the syntax to bind the variable to vairable $employeeid.

Is this the correct and best method for fetching and outputting the result of a mysql query that outputs a single record? if not please can you advise with a working example.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: apologies, corrected question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a parameter `:empid` in your query, and you have to pass a value for that parameter. No value means a empty resultset.

When using a binding parameter, you have to prepare the query, bind the parameter and then execute the query.

```
function get_editusers($db, $id){     
  try { 
    $result = $db->prepare("
     SELECT firstname, middlename,surname,fullname,gender,
     birthdate,homelanguage,department,employeetype,employeestatus,idnumber 
     FROM Persons where employeeid= :empid");

    $result->bindParam(':empid', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->execute();         
    return $result;  
} 
  catch(PDOException $ex) { 
    return $ex; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks JvdBerg, can you assist with a code snippet for me, jsut needing some guidance? Thanks,

Comment: Thanks JvdBerg, I updated the code as mentioned except changed variable $id to $employeeid to suit my code. I now get error:'Missing argument 2 for get_editusers()...' any advice. thanks

Comment: You have to change the call also: `$useredit= get_editusers($db, $id);`

Comment: Thanks JvdBerg, is this method better then what surffan has suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your parameter :empid before you execute the query.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT firstname, middlename FROM Persons where employeeid= :empid");
$sth->bindParam(':empid', $emp_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetch();
echo $row['firstname'];
```

Comment: Thanks surffan, is this method better than what JvdBerg suggested below?

Comment: As JvdBerg said it is the same method as it is shown in the PHP documentation http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindparam.php